# A records not found; non-www isn't working

Tags: centos, redirect, bind

I recently setup bind on CentOS and want to redirect the non-www to www part of the site.

Currently the `www` works, but when I try the bare domain from Safari I get: *Can't open http://mydomain.com because the server can't find mydomain.com*.

My zone file looks like this: (without the $TTL part below)

```
                IN NS         ns1.mydomain.com.
                IN A          [ip here]

      ns1       IN A          [ip here]

      @         IN MX 10      aspmx.l.google.com.
      @         IN MX 20      alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.

      *         IN CNAME      [ip here]
```

IntoDNS reports at "WWW A Record" section:

> ERROR: I could not get any A records for mydomain.com!

When I try `* IN A [ip]` I get the following error:

```
      Stopping named:                                            [  OK  ]
      Starting named: 
      Error in named configuration:
      zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 42
      dns_master_load: /var/named/mydomain.com.zone:19: *.mydomain.com: CNAME and other data
      zone mydomain.com/IN: loading from master file /var/named/mydomain.com.zone failed: CNAME and other data
      zone mydomain.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
      _default/mydomain.com/IN: CNAME and other data
                                                                 [FAILED]
```

But `IN A [ip]` - without * - works (as it was above).

Comment: I'm neither a Bind expert nor did I work with wildcards before, but CNAME to [ip here] looks wrong, CNAMES don't point to IPs, try 'A' instead of 'CNAME' ?

Comment: @Gryphius: Thanks, tried that but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: "It doesn't work at all" is not a very good problem description. What happens when you try to resolve? Do you get an IP address?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks. I've tried what you've suggested and updated my post. Safari simply doesn't load the non-www of the domain, while with www works. (also added in my post now)

Comment: @Max: Your post said you had a `CNAME`. We are suggesting using an `A` record. "dns_master_load: /var/named/mydomain.com.zone:19: *.mydomain.com: CNAME and other data" You shouldn't be using a `CNAME`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Oh sorry, my mistake. I've removed CNAME and still not working.

Comment: @Max: Okay, now that you've fixed that, what's the problem now? Saying "still not working" is not helpful. Obviously, you're not getting the same error (CNAME and other data).

Comment: The world has far more than enough broken DNS systems already, please don't add yours to the list. RTFM answers are frowned upon here but a question like just screams it out. Read the docs, that's what they're for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make `example.com` resolve to an IP address, add an `A` record for `@`.

```
@               IN      A       198.51.100.250
```

Comment: Yep, did that eventually and after propagating properly it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

DNS doesn't work like that.  CNAMEs map names to other names, not addresses; A records map names to addresses.

Comment: Also tried with `* IN CNAME mydomain.com`, `mydomain.com IN A [ip]`. Nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Try `* IN A [ip]`. If that doesn't work, please explain precisely what goes wrong when you do it. (Don't forget to bump the serial number and tell your name server that you've changed the zone.)

Comment: I think you mean @, not *. I doubt he wants a catch-all.